# Use Stokes Theorem to Prove Two Integrals on Differentiable Manifiolds are equivalent

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, stokes-theorem, manifolds-with-boundary

I have to answer the following problem:

Let $\omega= ydx + xzdy + xdz$.

Let $S_1$ be the portion of the upper hemisphere given by $\phi_1(u,v)=(u,v,\sqrt{4-u^2-v^2})$; where $u^2 + v^2 \leq 2$.

Let $S_2$ be the disc in the plane $z=\sqrt{2}$, given by $\phi_2(u,v)=(u,v,\sqrt{2})$; where $u^2 + v^2 \leq 2$.

Use Stokes theorem to show $\int\int_{s_1}d\omega=\int\int_{s_2}d\omega$

I know that I could technically calculate each integral to prove this, but since the directions are asking for the use of Stokes theorem, I feel like there's some trick that I'm missing. The two parameterizations look like they have equivalent boundaries, but I'm getting stuck on exactly how to show that. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think your first equation should say $d\omega$. No?

Comment: Hint:

Picture the surface $S:= S_1 \cup S_2$ (the upper hemisphere with a closed disk as a cap).

Consider the counterclockwise circular path $C$ around the disk. Stokes' theorem says that the line integral around $C$ is equal to the surface integral over $S_1$ of the curl. The same also holds in that the same line integral is equivalent to the surface integral over $S_2$ of the curl. They are equal by showing that if $A=B$ and $C=B$, then $A=C$. That's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: When $u^2+v^2=2$, we have $\sqrt{4-u^2-v^2}=\sqrt2$. Indeed,
$$\int_{S_1}d\omega=\int_{\partial S_1} \omega=\int_{\partial S_2} \omega=\int_{S_2} d\omega.$$